# Seaborn relplots creates duplicated axes

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

I'am trying to create two plots - one under another with seaborn!
My code:

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, sharex=True, figsize=(22,8))
p1 = sns.relplot(x="sns_codes", y="triad_quantity", hue="label", data=data_2, kind="line", ax=ax1)
p2 = sns.relplot(x="sns_codes", y="triad_quantity", hue="label", data=data_2, kind="line", ax=ax2)
```

But this creates 4 axes instead of 2! Look:

[image]

I give up getting read of these extra 2 axeses - need help.
Here's code to create data:

```
df ={'label': {0: 'top_5',
  1: 'first_page',
  2: 'win_ratecard',
  4: 'switched_off',
  5: 'top_5',
  6: 'first_page',
  7: 'win_ratecard',
  9: 'switched_off',
  10: 'top_5',
  11: 'first_page'},
 'report_date': {0: Timestamp('2018-08-21 00:00:00'),
  1: Timestamp('2018-08-21 00:00:00'),
  2: Timestamp('2018-08-21 00:00:00'),
  4: Timestamp('2018-08-22 00:00:00'),
  5: Timestamp('2018-08-22 00:00:00'),
  6: Timestamp('2018-08-22 00:00:00'),
  7: Timestamp('2018-08-22 00:00:00'),
  9: Timestamp('2018-08-23 00:00:00'),
  10: Timestamp('2018-08-23 00:00:00'),
  11: Timestamp('2018-08-23 00:00:00')},
 'sns_codes': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 4: 1, 5: 1, 6: 1, 7: 1, 9: 2, 10: 2, 11: 2},
 'triad_quantity': {0: 9,
  1: 204,
  2: 214,
  4: 20,
  5: 5,
  6: 191,
  7: 230,
  9: 21,
  10: 2,
  11: 98}}
 data_2 = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

Comment: Why are you doing that? `relplot` is a figure-level function, it will create its own `Figure` instance and potentially several subplots. What's the point in asking it to plot to a particular axes? It doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [seaborn is not plotting within defined subplots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63895392/seaborn-is-not-plotting-within-defined-subplots)

Comment: The existing solutions on this page no longer work. sns.relplot is a figure-level plot. See the previous linked duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is a possible solution to get rid of the additional unwanted empty plots. The problem was that when you call `sns.relplot`, `relplot` returns a `class:FacetGrid object`. This can be seen [here](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.relplot.html). But since you pass `ax1` and `ax2` for plotting, these FacetGrids which are assigned the variables `p1` and `p2` appear as blank plots. To get rid of these just add the following lines

```
plt.close(p1.fig)
plt.close(p2.fig)
```

Comment: This is not, what i dreamed for, but it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

relplot is a [figure-level](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/relational.html) function, so it will create a figure. If you want to put your lineplots in existing matplotlib axes, without creating the extraneous figures, use seaborn's lineplot function, which is an [axes-level](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/relational.html) function:

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, sharex=True, figsize=(22,8))
p1 = sns.lineplot(x="sns_codes", y="triad_quantity", hue="label", data=data_2, kind="line", ax=ax1)
p2 = sns.lineplot(x="sns_codes", y="triad_quantity", hue="label", data=data_2, kind="line", ax=ax2)
```

The two plots you've given as an example seem to do the same thing, but if you're trying to do multiple plots that vary along some dimension represented as a column in your dataframe, you can don't have to specify the subplots yourself. You can use seaborn to do this using sns.replot, with a row (facet) parameter specifying `row="a_column_on_which_your_plots_vary"`. See the [seaborn tutorial](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/relational.html#showing-multiple-relationships-with-facets) for an illustration.