# seaborn is not plotting within defined subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, subplot, facet-grid

I am trying to plot two displots side by side with this code

```
fig,(ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2)

sns.displot(x =X_train['Age'], hue=y_train, ax=ax1)
sns.displot(x =X_train['Fare'], hue=y_train, ax=ax2)
```

It returns the following result (two empty subplots followed by one displot each on two lines)-

[image]

[image]

[image]

If I try the same code with violinplot, it returns result as expected

```
fig,(ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2)

sns.violinplot(y_train, X_train['Age'], ax=ax1)
sns.violinplot(y_train, X_train['Fare'], ax=ax2)
```

[image]

Why is displot returning a different kind of output and what can I do to output two plots on the same line?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

- [`seaborn.distplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.distplot.html) has been `DEPRECATED` in `seaborn 0.11` and is replaced with the following:

  - [`displot()`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.displot.html#seaborn.displot), a figure-level function with a similar flexibility over the kind of plot to draw. This is a [`FacetGrid`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html#seaborn.FacetGrid), and does not have the `ax` parameter, so **it will not work with `matplotlib.pyplot.subplots`**.
  - [`histplot()`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.histplot.html#seaborn.histplot), an axes-level function for plotting histograms, including with kernel density smoothing. This does have the `ax` parameter, so **it will work with `matplotlib.pyplot.subplots`**.
- **It is applicable to any of the `seaborn` `FacetGrid` plots that there is no `ax` parameter. Use the equivalent axes-level plot.**

  - Look at the documentation for the figure-level plot to find the appropriate axes-level plot function for your needs.
  - See [Figure-level vs. axes-level functions](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/function_overview.html#figure-level-vs-axes-level-functions)

    - Figure-Level: [`relplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.relplot.html), [`displot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.displot.html#seaborn.displot), [`catplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html)
- Because the histogram of two different columns is desired, it's easier to use `histplot`.
- See [How to plot in multiple subplots](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69228859/7758804) for a number of different ways to plot into `maplotlib.pyplot.subplots`
- Also review [seaborn histplot and displot output doesn't match](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68865538/7758804)
- Tested in `seaborn 0.11.1` & `matplotlib 3.4.2`

```py
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)

sns.histplot(x=X_train['Age'], hue=y_train, ax=ax1)
sns.histplot(x=X_train['Fare'], hue=y_train, ax=ax2)
```

### Imports and DataFrame Sample

```py
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# load data
penguins = sns.load_dataset("penguins", cache=False)

# display(penguins.head())
  species     island  bill_length_mm  bill_depth_mm  flipper_length_mm  body_mass_g     sex
0  Adelie  Torgersen            39.1           18.7              181.0       3750.0    MALE
1  Adelie  Torgersen            39.5           17.4              186.0       3800.0  FEMALE
2  Adelie  Torgersen            40.3           18.0              195.0       3250.0  FEMALE
3  Adelie  Torgersen             NaN            NaN                NaN          NaN     NaN
4  Adelie  Torgersen            36.7           19.3              193.0       3450.0  FEMALE
```

### Axes Level Plot

- With the data in a wide format, use `sns.histplot`
- `.ravel`, `.flatten`, and `.flat` all convert the `axes` array to 1-D.

  - [What is the difference between flatten and ravel functions in numpy?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28930465/7758804)
  - [numpy difference between flat and ravel()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38357811/7758804)
  - [How to fix 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'get_figure' when plotting subplots](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64229894/7758804)

```py
# select the columns to be plotted
cols = ['bill_length_mm', 'bill_depth_mm']

# create the figure and axes
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2)
axes = axes.ravel()  # flattening the array makes indexing easier

for col, ax in zip(cols, axes):
    sns.histplot(data=penguins[col], kde=True, stat='density', ax=ax)

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

### Figure Level Plot

- With the dataframe in a long format, use `displot`

```py
# create a long dataframe
dfl = penguins.melt(id_vars='species', value_vars=['bill_length_mm', 'bill_depth_mm'], var_name='bill_size', value_name='vals')

# display(dfl.head())
  species       bill_size  vals
0  Adelie  bill_length_mm  39.1
1  Adelie   bill_depth_mm  18.7
2  Adelie  bill_length_mm  39.5
3  Adelie   bill_depth_mm  17.4
4  Adelie  bill_length_mm  40.3

# plot
sns.displot(data=dfl, x='vals', col='bill_size', kde=True, stat='density', common_bins=False, common_norm=False, height=4, facet_kws={'sharey': False, 'sharex': False})
```

---

#### Multiple DataFrames

- If there are multiple dataframes, they can be combined with `pd.concat`, and use `.assign` to create an identifying `'source'` column, which can be used for `row=`, `col=`, or `hue=`

```py
# list of dataframe
lod = [df1, df2, df3]

# create one dataframe with a new 'source' column to use for row, col, or hue
df = pd.concat((d.assign(source=f'df{i}') for i, d in enumerate(lod, 1)), ignore_index=True)
```

- See [Import multiple csv files into pandas and concatenate into one DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21232849/7758804) to read multiple files into a single dataframe with an identifying column.